# Scale Movieclip child elements using CreateJS

Tags: javascript, createjs

My old project is developed using Createjs. I need to scaleout movieclip but it's not scaling it's child objects.

```
let stage = new createjs.Stage('canvas2');
    stage.mouseMoveOutside = true; 
    stage.enableMouseOver(30);

    let mc = new createjs.MovieClip();

    let circle = new createjs.Shape( 
                         new createjs.Graphics().beginFill("#999999").drawCircle(0,0,100) 
                         );

    mc.addChild(circle)

    stage.addChild(mc)

    let img = new Image();
    img.src="images/testimages/we2.jpg";


    img.onload=(e)=>{

        let b = new createjs.Bitmap(e.target);
            mc.addChild(b);

            mc.scale=.2;
            
            setTimeout(()=>{
                mc.scale=.2;
            },1000)

        }

    window.createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick',function(e){
        stage.update(e);
    })
```

I need to scale Movieclip after loading image but it's doing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `mc.scale=.2;`, if I chain the X and Y settings then it works:

```
mc.scaleX = mc.scaleY = 0.2;
```